# What is the biggest sports stadium in the world?

Tags: statistics, records, trivia, venues

Which sports stadium (meaning any building designed to host sporting events) in the world, is the largest and who plays there? I'm thinking the largest as in the amount of people it can hold, but if you can come up with something different to go by, that's fine.

I am including any stadium that was made or designed to house any sort of sporting event. Motor racing is considered a sport so that is valid.

I think I read somewhere that the University of Michigan Wolverines have the largest capacity stadium in the USA. Is that true? And if so are there any larger than that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you refer to the most people attended in a sport match:

> [Indianapolis Motor Speedway][2] (motor racing venue) is the largest in the world with an capacity of **400,000** located at Speedway, Indiana, United States (although it has a [seating capacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indianapolis_Motor_Speedway) of 257,325 it has a infield seating that raises the capacity to an approximate 400,000).

You can read about more sporting venues with a highest attendance at the following [Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sporting_venues_with_a_highest_attendance_of_100,000_or_more).

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty general question, but Wikipedia has a great list of [capacity for sports stadiums around the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stadiums_by_capacity).

This articles notes that [Rungrado May Day Stadium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rungrado_May_Day_Stadium) in Pyongyang, North Korea has the largest capacity in the world at 150,000. The second largest, Salt Lake Stadium in Kolkata, India, has 30,000 less capcaity. The Korea DPR national football team plays in Rungrado May Day Stadium.

In the United States, it is [Michigan Stadium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_Stadium) in Ann Arbor, Michigan. This is also the third largest stadium in the world. Michigan Stadium, sometimes referred to as "The Big House," hosts the University of Michigan Wolverines football team and has a capacity of 109,901.

Comment: The UMich Big House seats something like 124,000 for hockey which is beyond ridiculous.  When I was working in Ann Arbor I wandered around the stadium and it is truly monstrous!

Answer (score 6):

The largest sports stadium is the Strahov Stadium in Prague with a capacity of 220,000. Now closed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strahov_Stadium

Comment: Touche. I was dumb enough to only look at stadiums that are currently used by sports teams. Nice job.